# Google play store app not showing latest version?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

The play store app does not update my app that is currently in beta. With `phone 1` I tested the app on release 2 I am currently on release 5 and when I follow the link I get from the dev console I still see release 2 there with old images, banners and screenshots.

On `phone 2` I tested it on release 3 and I still see this release instead of the latest release 5.

When I follow the same link on my desktop browser it shows the correct version.

Both version 4 and 5 are released/published, the dev console does not say "processing for publish" and more and release 4 was some days ago.

I just found this out and have spammed a ton about the new releases to my testers. It is kinda annoying that they cannot get to the latest version. I'm also worried that when I publish my app to the public I cannot push a new release perhaps a hotfix to my users.

Is there perhaps something I need to include in the manifest? And if so, how do I get the new versions to my current testers? I tried removing the app from the phone and clicking the test link again but this still shows the first version that phone downloaded in the app store.

If I remove the app and try to download it again from the link I get an error on the Google play store about "info cannot be retrieved from server", after that the play store app hangs/crashes.

Comment: How do I contact google? I cannot find am email,  phone number or anything for contacting them regarding this issue. They earn billions each year but support is poor for a company dealing with so much people and there privacy.

Comment: Try contacting them [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/?#topic=3450769) via the "Contact Us" tab at the top right. Then go to "publishing apps on Google Play" -> "Error when publishing an app" -> "email"

Comment: @RuchirBaronia Google is sometimes very slow and I believe this took more then a week. A friend of me called he finally could get the update. It is very annoying it takes this long since when I upload a new version I want to report that to my testers and blog about what's new. Now I have to keep checking if the update is finally available and then add it to my blog.